# GCP Gitlab CI Cloud Function NodeJs Deployment failed: RESOURCE_ERROR 400

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gitlab, continuous-integration

When trying to deploy a cloud function on gcp using SLS I receive the following exception

```
{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"Build failed: Build error details not available."}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to define in `.gitlab-ci.yml` the specific version of the image that the ci is running in by specifying the following key value: `image: node:12-alpine` at the top of the `.gitlab-ci.yml`.